# How to import IConfiguration in Blazor server side razor component?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a razor component that I want to use a configuration value on, from my appsettings.json file, and I've followed the example here: [Inject an IConfiguration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1#memory-configuration-source)

But that doesn't work inside the @code block for me.

My razor component looks like this so far:

```
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
@inject IConfiguration Configuration

@code {
    private string strValue = Configuration.GetSection("MySection").Value;
}
```

I get the following error on the Configuration.GetSection line:

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or
> property 'MyComponent.Configuration'

I can apparently use @Configuration outside of the @code section without error.

Am I missing something? I wasn't able to find a post relating to this exact issue, so sorry if this is a duplicate.

Comment: Another way to load settings https://stackoverflow.com/a/63583894/1492496. Intellisense  also works with this.

Comment: This is a standard C# rule/error, nothing to with Blazor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
@code {
    private string strValue;
  
  protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    strValue = Configuration.GetSection("MySection").Value;

}
}
```

You can't define and initialize the variable `strValue` by calling `Configuration.GetSection` at the same time. You ordinarily have to define a variable, and then populate it with a value returned by a method call, in the OnInitialized(Async) pair.

Comment: You are my hero! I wasn't aware that was a limitation in razor!